# How to enter apostrophe (') into mysql database in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, rmysql

A

```
ui.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  bootstrapPage(



  )
)
)

Server.R

library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
mydb=dbConnect(MySQL(),user='',password='123',dbname='test1',host='localhost')
shinyServer(function(input, output,session){


column(4, 
                    textInput("name", label = "NAME:", 
                              value ='')),
             column(4, 
                    textInput("address", label = "Address:", 
                              value =''))

column(2,
                              actionButton("add", "ADD"))



 observeEvent(
    input$add, 
 output$ui123 <- renderUI({isolate({

dbSendQuery(mydb,paste("INSERT INTO table1(name,address) VALUES ('",input$name,"','",input$address,"');",sep=" ")) 
})}))


  }



})
```

If the input to address contains apostrophe (for example:First street's),then it shows an error that the mysql statement contains some error. How can this data be entered without any error into Mysql in R shiny.

Comment: you're obviously vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), if a `'` kills your query. you should learn how to prevent that.

Comment: Can you use a prepared statement?

Comment: I was not able to prevent that error in Rshiny.

Comment: you could use `sprintf("INSERT INTO table1(name,address) VALUES ('%s','%s');", input$name, input$address)`, but you should also validate/sanitize the inputs.

Comment: Sir, I used dbEscapeStrings() before the dbsendQuery statement but got error.Sir how to validate the inputs in Rshiny.

Comment: Sir sprintf  also showed the same error.

Answer (score -1):

maybe juste add slashes (like php) :

```
gsub(pattern = "'", replacement = "\\\\'", x = "test'")
```

?